# jQueryUI Templating: Does It Work, Will It Work?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a need to modify the code emitted by [jQueryUI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).  The `tabTemplate` option seems ideal for that purpose.

I modified my code to include a custom style:

```
tabControl = $("#tabs");
tabControl.tabs({
    tabTemplate: '<li><a href="#{href}" class="myClass"><span>#{label}</span></a></li>',
});
```

However, I found that the emitted code did not change.  Then, I came across this ticket

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7139

claiming that templating in general is being depreciated (as of 12 months ago).

So... why isn't tabTemplate working, is this solution future-proof, and if not, how can I achieve a similar end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI is indeed deprecating the templating options (apparently because their use could result in style inconsistencies with the rest of the library).

According to the bug you link to, the `tabTemplate` option will be removed in jQuery UI 1.9, so, to be on the safe side, you should avoid using it in your current projects.

An alternative is to add the classes through DOM navigation, as follows:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    // options...
}).tabs("widget").find(".ui-tabs-nav a").addClass("myClass");
```

This approach works now and will continue to work in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Perfect.  I filed a bug report with jQueryUI to document tabTemplate as obsolete.